# setting up a web server with static ip address using arduino

Tags: arduino, iot

this code print the ip address at run time on serial monitor i want to set it at the the time of programming.i am using arduino ide for programming an iot device.this is an example code from arduino.i am using an esp8266 ic for wifi connection.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
char ssid[] = "yourNetwork";      // your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "secretPassword";   // your network password
int keyIndex = 0;                 // your network key Index number (needed        only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while (!Serial) {
; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
    // don't continue:
    while(true);
  } 

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP                 network:    
status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  server.begin();
  // you're connected now, so print out the status:
  printWifiStatus();
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
// an http request ends with a blank line
boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
while (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
    // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
    // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
    // so you can send a reply
    if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      // send a standard http response header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
      client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
      client.println();
      client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
      client.println("<html>");
      // output the value of each analog input pin
      for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
        int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
        client.print("analog input ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is ");
        client.print(sensorReading);
        client.println("<br />");       
      }
      client.println("</html>");
       break;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
      // you're starting a new line
      currentLineIsBlank = true;
    } 
    else if (c != '\r') {
      // you've gotten a character on the current line
      currentLineIsBlank = false;
    }
  }
}
// give the web browser time to receive the data
delay(1);

// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Comment: are you trying to setup a web server with a static IP? With the sample code given you are only connecting to your personal wifi network.

Comment: Why not following this tutorial? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer